# Ansibleのgitモジュールで指定したgitlabのリポジトリの記述が空になってしまう

Tags: gitlab, ansible

ymlファイルにgitモジュールのgitコマンドを記入し 
実行しようとしたところ 
playbookの実行時に指定した"repo=●●●"  
「●●●」部分が空になっているようで、さらにタイムアウトもせずにplaybook実行が止まってしまいます。

```
- name: gitでリポジトリの取得 
  git: repo=git@gitlab.mm.com:sample.git dest=/home/test version=origin accept_hostkey=yes
```

playbook実行中のログを取得すると

> <192.168.0.1> REMOTE_MODULE git repo= dest=/home/test version=master accept_hostkey=yes

となってしまいます。 
試しにssh取得ではなくhttp取得に変えたところ 
repoが空になるという現象は発生しませんでした。

①何かssh取得できない要因があるのでしょうか

言葉足らずであれば申し訳御座いません。 
宜しくお願い致します。

環境は 
Linux version 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) ) #1

Ansible 1.9.4-1.el7 
です。

Comment: マルチポスト。https://teratail.com/questions/30082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しましたので、記載しておきます。

Ansibleのgithubで公開されていたコードを解析してみたところ
repoの値を補完する処理を見つけまして解析しておりました。

また他の方にご教授いただきまして、スキームを足すとこの処理が
うまく保管をしてくれるようですので
以下でうまくいくようです。

```
- name: gitでリポジトリの取得 
  git: repo=ssh://git@gitlab.mm.com:sample.git dest=/home/test version=origin accept_hostkey=yes
```

> 解析したCode
>   [Ansibleコード解析部分](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/known_hosts.py#L73-L101/)